# The composer install command gives illegal offset type error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I run the `composer install` command on my laravel project, I get this error:

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   ErrorException  : Illegal offset type
   at /var/www/routes/web.php:57

    56| $blah = app('config')->get('app.api_content_type_map');
  > 57| $bb = $blah[$lang];
```

Exception trace:

```
  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError()
      /var/www/routes/web.php:57

  2   Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:414

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
  Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I have this in my `config/app.php`

```
'api_content_type_map' => [
  'en'=>[
    'news'=>'article',
    'page'=>'page'
  ],
  'fr'=>[
    'nouvelles'=>'article',
    'page'=>'page'
  ]
],
```

What did I do wrong?

---

UPDATE 1

This is the output of my `php -v`

```
PHP 7.4.2 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2020 11:21:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

---

UPDATE 2

I deleted line 57, `php artisan config:clear`, add back the line`,`composer install`, and still get the same error message. I went to another computer, did a fresh checkout of the project, tried to run`composer install`, also the same error. So I'm thinking it's not actually some cache issue?

Comment: What does `php -v` output?

Comment: In Tinker (`php artisan tinker`), what does `app('config')->get('app.api_content_type_map')` output? Can you try a `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: My suspicion is your config is cached, and that `$blah` is null instead of an array because of that. You can temporarily remove the two lines from `routes/web.php` to get Tinker working again.

Comment: yes, removing those lines allows me to install again

Comment: OK. A `php artisan config:clear` should clear out a cached config you may have. After that, try adding the lines back.

Comment: I deleted the lines, `php artisan config:clear`, add back the lines, `composer install`, and still get the same error message.  I went to another computer, did a fresh checkout of the project, tried to run `composer install`, also the same error. So I'm thinking it's not actually some cache issue?

Comment: Please remove the lines, then in `php artisan tinker` do `app('config')->get('app.api_content_type_map')` and make sure it outputs what you expect. After that, try `app('config')->get('app.api_content_type_map.en')`. Please also indicate how `$lang` is set in your routes file, and try changing `$bb = $blah[$lang];` to `$bb = $blah['en'];` to check that part.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved...My `$lang` was null because it is dependent on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which apparently is null during `composer install`.